# Reducing upload_max_filesize in openshift php app

Tags: php, file-upload, openshift, ini

I just updated `upload_max_filesize` to 2M and `post_max_size` to 4M in php.ini at `/var/lib/openshift/xxx---app-id---xxx/php/configuration/etc/php.ini` in my scalable PHP app and restarted the cartridge:

```
  $ rhc cartridge restart php -a "myapp"
```

And then the app

```
  $ rhc app restart -a "myapp"
```

But unfortunately, the upload size still remains the default 200 MB.

Please tell me where else to modify and what else to do to reduce maximum file upload size because 200 MB size is too large and dangerous to be public in my app.

Comment: You might try using ini_set in your code instead of modifying the php.ini file.

Comment: @developercorey. Thanks for your reply but I don't think `upload_max_size` is changeable through `init_set` bacause it is of mode `PHP_INI_PERDIR` which cannot be changed through php code in php5.3+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding these into your .htaccess?

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 2M
php_value post_max_size 4M
```

Comment: Well for some reasons I didn't want to edit `.htaccess` but there was no other choice left. Hence answer accepted and +1'd. Thank you.

Comment: But is there a reason why editing `php.ini` at `*****/php/configuration/etc/` or adding new one at `*****/app-root/runtime/repo/` didn't work?

Comment: @TabrezAhmed when you restart your cartridge or your app any change made to php.ini is reset to default so is because is neede to write some values in .htaccess